# Gradle keeps getting a "Could not get unknown property for root project" error

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

As someone new to gradle, I'm trying to have my build step depend on a custom task.

My `build.gradle` contains this code:

```
repositories {
  jcenter()
}

apply plugin: 'base'

defaultTasks 'build'
build.dependsOn compileAll

task compileAll {
  doLast {
    println "hello" 
  }
}
```

If I remove the `build.dependsOn compileAll` line, this works fine. I think I'm doing something wrong but I'm not sure what.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Problem is that you create the dependency between `build` and `compileAll` before you actually declare  the `compileAll` task. So Gradle does not know about this task and generates the error `Could not get property...`. 
Remember that build scripts in are actually real SCRIPTs, the order instructions/blocks matters.

This will work:

```
// first declare "compileAll" task
task compileAll {
    doLast {
        println "hello"
    }
}
// then you can reference this compileAll task declare above
build.dependsOn compileAll
```